# Can anyone tell me why my redirect helper does not work the way I'd expect it to?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to redirect to the other method in same controller, but it takes me **http://localhost/ajaxTutorial/welcome/localhost/ajaxTutorial/welcome/index**  means it merge the both links. Does this make sense to anyone?

this is my controller code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('welcome_model', 'model');
        

    }

    public function index()
    {       
            $this->load->view('login');
        
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $pass = $_POST['password'];
            $modelData = $this->model->login($email , $pass);

            if (!isset($modelData)) {
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $modelData['id'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $modelData['username'];
                echo json_encode($modelData);

            }else{
                echo json_encode($modelData);
            }
            
        }else {
             $modelData = array('Emailerr' => form_error('email'), 'Passerr'=>form_error('password'));
            echo json_encode($modelData);
        }
    }
    public function dashboard()
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            
            redirect('welcome/index');
        } else {
            echo "welcome";
                
        }
        
    }
```

Does anyone have advice on how to fix this issue?

Comment: please share your code so we can identify the issue

Comment: That `localhost` in the middle probably means you did a redirect to `localhost/ajaxTutorial/welcome/index` when you should've done `http://localhost/ajaxTutorial/welcome/index` or `/ajaxTutorial/welcome/index`...

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect - you don't need to specify the fully qualified URL, but it should be absolute, eg `redirect('/welcome/index');`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
return redirect('your_relative_path');
```

Comment: `return` is not used with `redirect()`: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect

Comment: Oops, I didn't take note of the version, that is version 4 way of doing it,  anyway, I think you should try using `return( ' / ' )` instead